# How to use an extra webcam on android?

Tags: android

I have got android 3.1,it got usb API.So I'd like to use an extra usb webcam,but I dont know how to do.Can somebody please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you use this API:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html

In that case, you need to re-implement your camera driver in Java. Perhaps [gspca](http://mxhaard.free.fr/download.html) sources will help.

Comment: Thanks,Koterpillar.But when I looked into google's sample: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/USB/MissileLauncher/index.html,it seems they use just apk without driver.So is there a way to do this without driver?